# GRPC Ver 1.22.0 DNS resolution failed

Tags: c#, wpf, grpc, google-speech-api

When I created the channel for Google Speech Client through the proxy(also PAC), I got the DNS resolution failed.This porblem only occur in my customer side but do not occur in my company proxy. Can you advice for this issue and also what information need for to do this from my customer side?

My environment informations are following.

> C# / net462 gRPC 1.22.0 , Google.cloud.speech.v1 Windows 10

My codes are following.

```
var cred = GoogleAuthentication.GetServiceAccountCredential(GoogleSpeech.SpeechClient.DefaultScopes);
ChannelCredentials channelCredentials = cred.ToChannelCredentials();
Channel channel = new Channel(GoogleSpeech.SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,GoogleSpeech.SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, channelCredentials);
GoogleSpeechClient = GoogleSpeech.SpeechClient.Create(channel);
```

Here is my grpc debug log.

> I0205 11:22:45.653978 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\transport\chttp2\client\secure\secure_channel_create.cc:198:
>   grpc_secure_channel_create(creds=00000204FCF267F0,
>   target=speech.googleapis.com:443, args=00000204A2666570,
>   reserved=0000000000000000) I0205 11:22:45.653978 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1184:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: creating client_channel for channel stack
>   00000204FDDCBFA0 I0205 11:22:45.653978 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: update: state=IDLE picker=00000204A2666770
>   I0205 11:22:45.653978 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1259:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: created resolving_lb_policy=000002049E1046E0
>   I0205 11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\metadata_array.cc:29:
>   grpc_metadata_array_init(array=00000204A2666690) I0205 11:22:45.655974
>   0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1922:
>   grpc_call_start_batch(call=000002049E2DB960, ops=00000009C19FD620,
>   nops=2, tag=00000204A2557130, reserved=0000000000000000) I0205
>   11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1526:
>   ops[0]: SEND_INITIAL_METADATA key=x-goog-api-client value=67 6c 2d 64
>   6f 74 6e 65 74 2f 34 2e 36 2e 32 20 67 63 63 6c 2f 31 2e 32 2e 30 20
>   67 61 70 69 63 2f 31 2e 32 2e 30 20 67 61 78 2f 32 2e 39 2e 30 20 67
>   72 70 63 2f 31 2e 32 32 2e 30 'gl-dotnet/4.6.2 gccl/1.2.0 gapic/1.2.0
>   gax/2.9.0 grpc/1.22.0' I0205 11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1526:
>   ops[1]: RECV_STATUS_ON_CLIENT metadata=00000204A2557190
>   status=00000204A25571A8 details=00000204A25571B0 I0205 11:22:45.655974
>   0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3499:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: LB pick returned QUEUE
>   (connected_subchannel=0000000000000000, error="No Error") I0205
>   11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3373:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: adding to queued picks
>   list I0205 11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc:283:
>   resolving_lb=000002049E1046E0: starting name resolution I0205
>   11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: update: state=CONNECTING
>   picker=00000204A2666AF0 D0205 11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:242:
>   Start resolving. I0205 11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3499:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: LB pick returned QUEUE
>   (connected_subchannel=0000000000000000, error="No Error") I0205
>   11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1922:
>   grpc_call_start_batch(call=000002049E2DB960, ops=00000009C19FD680,
>   nops=1, tag=00000204A2557200, reserved=0000000000000000) I0205
>   11:22:45.655974 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1526:
>   ops[0]: RECV_INITIAL_METADATA ptr=00000204A2557238 I0205
>   11:22:45.657332 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1922:
>   grpc_call_start_batch(call=000002049E2DB960, ops=00000009C19FDD20,
>   nops=1, tag=00000204A2556EC0, reserved=0000000000000000) I0205
>   11:22:45.657332 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1526:
>   ops[0]: SEND_MESSAGE ptr=00000204FDDE43D0 I0205 11:22:45.677333
>   2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:185:
>   dns resolution failed (will retry):
>   {"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}
>   I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc:299:
>   resolving_lb=000002049E1046E0: resolver transient failure:
>   {"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}
>   I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: update: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE
>   picker=00000204FAC0CC20 D0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:202:
>   retrying in 1000 milliseconds I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3499:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: LB pick returned
>   TRANSIENT_FAILURE (connected_subchannel=0000000000000000,
>   error={"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Resolver
>   transient
>   failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":307,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS
>   resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is
>   known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}) I0205
>   11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3361:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: removing from queued
>   picks list I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3308:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: failed to pick
>   subchannel:
>   error={"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Failed to pick
>   subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3528,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Resolver
>   transient
>   failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":307,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS
>   resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is
>   known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}]} I0205
>   11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:688:
>   cq_end_op_for_next(cq=000002049E247C30, tag=00000204A2557130,
>   error="No Error", done=00007FFDD8C1E1A0, done_arg=000002049E2DC7F0,
>   storage=000002049E2DC840) I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:688:
>   cq_end_op_for_next(cq=000002049E247C30, tag=00000204A2556EC0,
>   error={"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Failed to pick
>   subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3528,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Resolver
>   transient
>   failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":307,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS
>   resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is
>   known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}]},
>   done=00007FFDD8C1E1A0, done_arg=000002049E2DC9B0,
>   storage=000002049E2DCA00) I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:688:
>   cq_end_op_for_next(cq=000002049E247C30, tag=00000204A2557200,
>   error={"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Failed to pick
>   subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3528,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Resolver
>   transient
>   failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":307,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS
>   resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is
>   known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}]},
>   done=00007FFDD8C1E1A0, done_arg=000002049E2DC8D0,
>   storage=000002049E2DC920) I0205 11:22:45.677333 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:3337:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020 calld=000002049E2DC310: cancelling queued pick:
>   error={"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Failed to pick
>   subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3528,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Resolver
>   transient
>   failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":307,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS
>   resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is
>   known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}]}
>   self=00000204FDD77F90 calld->pick_canceller=0000000000000000 I0205
>   11:22:45.677333 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:1063: RETURN_EVENT[000002049E247C30]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:00000204A2557130 OK
>   I0205 11:22:45.677333 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:963:
>   grpc_completion_queue_next(cq=000002049E247C30, deadline=gpr_timespec
>   { tv_sec: 9223372036854775807, tv_nsec: 0, clock_type: 1 },
>   reserved=0000000000000000) I0205 11:22:45.677333 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:1063: RETURN_EVENT[000002049E247C30]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:00000204A2556EC0
>   ERROR I0205 11:22:45.677333 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:963:
>   grpc_completion_queue_next(cq=000002049E247C30, deadline=gpr_timespec
>   { tv_sec: 9223372036854775807, tv_nsec: 0, clock_type: 1 },
>   reserved=0000000000000000) I0205 11:22:45.677333 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:1063: RETURN_EVENT[000002049E247C30]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:00000204A2557200
>   ERROR I0205 11:22:45.678195 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:963:
>   grpc_completion_queue_next(cq=000002049E247C30, deadline=gpr_timespec
>   { tv_sec: 9223372036854775807, tv_nsec: 0, clock_type: 1 },
>   reserved=0000000000000000) D0205 11:22:45.698018 2218855401520
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:242:
>   Start resolving. I0205 11:22:45.698018 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:185:
>   dns resolution failed (will retry):
>   {"created":"@1580869365.698000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}
>   I0205 11:22:45.698018 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc:299:
>   resolving_lb=00000204A258E6E0: resolver transient failure:
>   {"created":"@1580869365.698000000","description":"DNS resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.698000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}
>   I0205 11:22:45.698987 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCDBE0: update: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE
>   picker=000002049E1EE100 D0205 11:22:45.698987 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:202:
>   retrying in 142172 milliseconds I0205 11:22:45.782621 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1922:
>   grpc_call_start_batch(call=000002049E2DB960, ops=00000009C05FE160,
>   nops=1, tag=00000204A2557130, reserved=0000000000000000) I0205
>   11:22:45.782621 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:1526:
>   ops[0]: RECV_MESSAGE ptr=00000204A2557180 I0205 11:22:45.782621 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:688:
>   cq_end_op_for_next(cq=000002049E247C30, tag=00000204A2557130,
>   error={"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Failed to pick
>   subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3528,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"Resolver
>   transient
>   failure","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":307,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"DNS
>   resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869365.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is
>   known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}]},
>   done=00007FFDD8C1E1A0, done_arg=000002049E2DCA90,
>   storage=000002049E2DCAE0) I0205 11:22:45.782621 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:1063: RETURN_EVENT[000002049E247C30]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:00000204A2557130
>   ERROR I0205 11:22:45.782621 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\completion_queue.cc:963:
>   grpc_completion_queue_next(cq=000002049E247C30, deadline=gpr_timespec
>   { tv_sec: 9223372036854775807, tv_nsec: 0, clock_type: 1 },
>   reserved=0000000000000000) I0205 11:22:45.783619 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc:573:
>   grpc_call_unref(c=000002049E2DB960) I0205 11:22:46.370273 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\security\credentials\credentials.cc:43:
>   grpc_channel_credentials_release(creds=00000204FCF267F0) I0205
>   11:22:46.370273 0
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\security\credentials\credentials.cc:43:
>   grpc_channel_credentials_release(creds=000002049E368640) D0205
>   11:22:46.676327 2218857935696
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:242:
>   Start resolving. I0205 11:22:46.677361 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:185:
>   dns resolution failed (will retry):
>   {"created":"@1580869366.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}
>   I0205 11:22:46.677361 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc:299:
>   resolving_lb=000002049E1046E0: resolver transient failure:
>   {"created":"@1580869366.677000000","description":"DNS resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869366.677000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}
>   I0205 11:22:46.677361 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: update: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE
>   picker=000002049E0947E0 D0205 11:22:46.677361 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:202:
>   retrying in 1616 milliseconds D0205 11:22:48.293939 2218855401520
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:242:
>   Start resolving. I0205 11:22:48.294441 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:185:
>   dns resolution failed (will retry):
>   {"created":"@1580869368.294000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}
>   I0205 11:22:48.294441 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc:299:
>   resolving_lb=000002049E1046E0: resolver transient failure:
>   {"created":"@1580869368.294000000","description":"DNS resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869368.294000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}
>   I0205 11:22:48.294441 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: update: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE
>   picker=000002049E094E60 D0205 11:22:48.294441 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:202:
>   retrying in 2336 milliseconds D0205 11:22:50.629492 2218857935696
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:242:
>   Start resolving. I0205 11:22:50.653821 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc:185:
>   dns resolution failed (will retry):
>   {"created":"@1580869370.653000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}
>   I0205 11:22:50.653821 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc:299:
>   resolving_lb=000002049E1046E0: resolver transient failure:
>   {"created":"@1580869370.654000000","description":"DNS resolution
>   failed","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\native\dns_resolver.cc","file_line":190,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580869370.653000000","description":"OS
>   Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No
>   such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}
>   I0205 11:22:50.653821 2218856014768
>   T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc:1087:
>   chand=00000204FDDCC020: update: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE
>   picker=000002049E0948C0 D0205 11:22:50.653821 221885601

Comment: This is a network issue, just try `ping speech.googleapis.com` in a command line from your client network to show the issue (`GoogleSpeech.SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint` is `speech.googleapis.com:443`). Take a appointment with the I.T. guy there and ask him to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

This issue already exist in [GRPC Ver 1.19](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18411), a proposed workaround is to set the `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER` environment variable to `native`.

```
// Do it early
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER", "native");
```

Comment: This GRPC log is the result after changing DNS_RESOLVER to Native.

Comment: @ammoe which log ? did you try something else than native ? (based on this: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md the other possible option is `ares`)